# Entity pulling in a ton of tables not in my query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

We have a table in our schema that normalizes data, we call it `DataPart`.  Roughly, its definition is:

```
DataPart
--------
DataPartId   int
Message      varchar(200)
CreatedDate  datetime
```

The POCO matches this:

```
public class DataPart {
    public long DataPartId {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts {get; set;}
    // and so on...
}
```

Since there are navigation properties (Album, Comment, Post all use a DataPart) we had to set up the primary key and key mapping properties with the model builder:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<DataPart> ()
    .HasOptional (x => x.Album)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal (x => x.DataPart);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<DataPart> ()
    .HasOptional (x => x.Comment)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal (x => x.DataPart);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<DataPart> ()
    .HasOptional (x => x.Post)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal (x => x.DataPart);

// and so on...
```

I wrote the following LINQ-to-Entities query:

```
var query =
    from DataPart dp in db.DataParts
    where dp.CreationDate >= dateFrom && dp.CreationDate <= dateTo;
```

LINQPad shows it doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` against all the tables have set up as navigation properties, even though none of them actually get pulled in with this query!

I'm thinking my problem is the `modelBuilder` stanza, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong.  Every Album/Comment/Post is required to have a DataPart, but a DataPart is only going to relate to one of 20-some-odd types of objects.  I've done .WithRequired, and the result is the same.

edit: The problem goes away if I actually select the pieces of information I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how EF behaves when you configure one-to-one relation. When you query the principal entity it will left join all optional one-to-one dependencies to know if they exists or not.

Why are you trying to map one-to-one relation when your snippet of `DataPart` class doesn't expect it? Your current mapping is not compatible with the class you showed.

Answer (score 0):

The "HasOptional" merely states that your DataPart can have 0 or more related Album / Comment / Post items (and that the foreign key can be null), hence the left outer join (which is equivalent to "return all DataParts plus 0 or more joined table items")

Your LINQ query returns DataPart objects. Those objects have navigation properties pointing to the tables you're seeing in the executed db query. Either the data for those navigation properties needs to be eager-loaded in the initial db query, or lazy-loaded when the properties are first accessed (or manually loaded - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx for loading details).

If you don't want them showing up in the initial db query, turn on lazy-loading for those navigation properties.

Comment: LazyLoading is enabled: `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true`.  Same issue.  Thoughts?